# Training gets slower over time (pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, memory-leaks

I'm training a variational autoencoder with pytorch and I'm having some troubles when training. At the beginning all is ok, but when several epochs are done then its computation time increases, as you can see in the picture.

[Time per epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7mb.jpg)

I tried some ways to fix that. First, I tried to monitor the used memory of cuda, and you can see in the picture it doesn't increase (there you only can see the allocated memory, but free and reserved are constant too). Then I tried with the command cuda.empty_cache(), to see if some tensor was storing data wihtout having to, but didn't work either.

I'd like to clarify that this problem only appeared when I gave more depth to the neural network, with a basic architecture this doesn't happen. Do you know what might be happening?

Feel free to ask for more details if proceed, and thanks in advance:D

EDIT: Link to github repo: https://github.com/protovich/mre

Comment: Without seeing the code, this is almost impossible to answer. Best if you could provide an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: True, sorry for that. A link to github repo's been added

Comment: I would note that the code has some mistakes, e.g. loss_function returns 4 variables but are passed to 3 variables. Do I understand correctly that the model VAE_basic doesn't have the problem but VAE does? How many trainable variables does VAE have, it seems very large...? I think this problem requires step by step debugging to narrow down the problem.

Comment: That's it. VAE_basic runs correctly but VAE gets slower over time. The first one has like 50 million trainable parameters, meanwhile VAE has about 400. That's why I think it must be something about memory leaks or similar

PD: that mistake you noted is true, but it's only of mre (i haven't checked it in detail), that's not the matter